# Creating a dataframe from monthly values which dont start on january

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, i have some data in list form, such as:

```
Q=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]                                     #values
M=[11,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]                                       #months
Y=[2010,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011]       #years
```

And i want to get a dataframe, with one row per year, and one column per month, adding the data of Q on the positions given by M and Y.

so far i have tried a couple of things, my current code is as follows:

```
def save_data(data_list,year_info,month_info):
    
    #how many datapoints
    n_data=len(data_list)
    
    #how many years
    y0=year_info[0]
    yf=year_info[n_data-1]
    n_years=yf-y0+1
    
    #creating the list i want to fill out
    df_list=[[math.nan]*12]*n_years
    
    ind=0
    for y in range(n_years):
        for m in range(12):
            if ind<len(data_list):
                if year_info[ind]-y0==y and month_info[ind]==m:
                    df_list[y][m]=data_list[ind]
                    ind+=1
    
        
    df=pd.DataFrame(df_list)
    
    return df
```

I get this output:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | nan | 2 |
| **1** | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | nan | 2 |

And i want to get:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 2 |
| **1** | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | nan | nan |

I have tried doing a bunch of diferent things, but so far nothing has worked, I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way of doing this, my code seems to be overwriting in a weird way, i do not know for instance why is there a 2 on the last value of second row, since that's the first value of my list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pivot`:

```
(pd.DataFrame({'Y':Y,'M':M,'Q':Q})
  .pivot(index='Y', columns='M', values='Q')
)
```

Output:

```
M      0    1    2    3    4    5    6     7     8     9    11
Y                                                             
2010  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  2.0
2011  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0  11.0  12.0  NaN
```